# How can I create contour shapes from a cloud of points in .NET

Tags: c#, gis

I have a long series of x and y points and a corresponding value. I need to find a .NET library that can help me create contours where I basically specify the point cloud and a threshold relating to the value in the points as arguments and then the library provides be back a list of geometries or shapes that defined the contours.

I have searched a lot on the internet, but my search hasn't been fruitful.

Any suggestions

Cheers
Franz Thomsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library called wCountour that I can get to do what I need